# sqoop-merge can this command use on hbase import?

Tags: hbase, sqoop

I use sqoop import data from sql server to hbase. Can I also use sqoop-merge command to update data in hbase?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sqoop-merge doesn't support hbase but running a new import (even from other sql table) will override the data in hbase. You can provide a custom where + custom columns to update just the data you need without affecting the rest of the data already stored in hbase:

```
sqoop import --connect [CONN_STRING] --username [USERNAME] --password [PASSWORD] \
--table my_mysql_table --hbase-table my_hbase_table --column-family info \
--where "date_updated >= (NOW()-INTERVAL 24 HOUR)" --columns "id, data"
```

This command will update the column `info:data` on `my_hbase_table` with the `data` field of every row of `my_mysql_table` with a `date_updated` field within the last 24 hours range (where condition would be different for SQL server)

Please notice you need to provide the columns conforming the hbase row key as column as well (`id` in this case), otherwise it won't work.

Comment: Thanks very much. One more question, in what condition can I use sqoop-merge? I mean which situation does sqoop-merge support?

Comment: Its used to merge datasets in HDFS. Take a look at this example in the sqoop docs: https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.0-incubating/SqoopUserGuide.html#id1770457